# R: obtain coefficients&CI from bootstrapping mixed-effect model results

Tags: r, lme4, statistics-bootstrap, coefficients

The working data looks like:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(1:30), 
                 fac1 = as.factor(sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"),30, replace = T)),
                 fac2 = as.factor(sample(c("NY","NC","CA"),30,replace = T)),
                 x = rnorm(1:30))
```

The `lme` model is fitted as:

```
library(lme4)
mixed <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|fac1) + (1|fac2), data = df)
```

I used `bootMer` to run the parametric bootstrapping and I can successfully obtain the coefficients (intercept) and SEs for fixed&random effects:

```
mixed_boot_sum <- function(data){s <- sigma(data)
c(beta = getME(data, "fixef"), theta = getME(data, "theta"), sigma = s)}

mixed_boot <- bootMer(mixed, FUN = mixed_boot_sum, nsim = 100, type = "parametric", use.u = FALSE)
```

My first question is how to obtain the coefficients(slope) of each individual levels of the two random effects from the bootstrapping results `mixed_boot` ?

I have no problem extracting the coefficients(slope) from `mixed` model by using `augment` function from `broom` package, see below:

```
library(broom)
mixed.coef <- augment(mixed, df)
```

However, it seems like `broom` can't deal with `boot` class object. I can't use above functions directly on `mixed_boot`.

I also tried to modify the `mixed_boot_sum` by adding `mmList`( I thought this would be what I am looking for), but R complains as：

```
Error in bootMer(mixed, FUN = mixed_boot_sum, nsim = 100, type = "parametric",  : 
  bootMer currently only handles functions that return numeric vectors
```

Furthermore, is it possible to obtain CI of both fixed&random effects by specifying `FUN` as well?

Now, I am very confused about the correct specifications for the `FUN` in order to achieve my needs. Any help regarding to my question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is how to obtain the coefficients(slope) of each individual levels of the two random effects from the bootstrapping results mixed_boot ?

I'm not sure what you mean by "coefficients(slope) of each individual level". `broom::augment(mixed, df)` gives the predictions (residuals, etc.) for *every observation*. If you want the predicted coefficients at each level I would try

```
mixed_boot_coefs <- function(fit){
   unlist(coef(fit))
}
```

which for the original model gives

```
mixed_boot_coefs(mixed)
## fac1.(Intercept)1 fac1.(Intercept)2 fac1.(Intercept)3 fac1.(Intercept)4 
##        -0.4973925        -0.1210432        -0.3260958         0.2645979 
## fac1.(Intercept)5           fac1.x1           fac1.x2           fac1.x3 
##        -0.6288728         0.2187408         0.2187408         0.2187408 
##           fac1.x4           fac1.x5 fac2.(Intercept)1 fac2.(Intercept)2 
##         0.2187408         0.2187408        -0.2617613        -0.2617613 
##  ...
```

If you want the resulting object to be more clearly named you can use:

```
flatten <- function(cc) setNames(unlist(cc),
                                outer(rownames(cc),colnames(cc),
                                      function(x,y) paste0(y,x)))

mixed_boot_coefs <- function(fit){
   unlist(lapply(coef(fit),flatten))
}
```

When run through `bootMer`/`confint`/`boot::boot.ci` these functions will give confidence intervals for each of these values (note that all of the slopes `facW.xZ` are identical across groups because the model assumes random variation in the intercept only).  In other words, whatever information you know how to extract from a fitted model (conditional modes/BLUPs [`ranef`], predicted intercepts and slopes for each level of the grouping variable [`coef`], parameter estimates [`fixef`, `getME`], random-effects variances [`VarCorr`], predictions under specific conditions [`predict`] ...) can be used in `bootMer`'s `FUN` argument, *as long as you can flatten its structure into a simple numeric vector*.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Ben Bolker. That works well.  One more question, is it possible to recover the original name of each level of grouping variable when using `coef` ? I see, in your results, R produces numeric for levels instead of the original names.